# Using Recipient.FreeBusy in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I am having trouble using the FreeBusy method of the Recipient class.

The documentation states that the function parameters are:

`Start` which represents the start time, `MinPerChar` which represents the minutes per character returned, and `CompleteFormat` which represents whether you just want to know if the room is busy or additional details about the business.

However, when putting the following code, I get the same results:

```
 debug.print myRoom.FreeBusy(#10/18/2016 11:00:00 AM#, 30, false)
```

which gives:

```
 0000000000000000010000001......
```

and then:

```
 debug.print myRoom.FreeBusy(#10/18/2016 10:00:00 AM#, 30, false)
```

gives the same thing:

```
 0000000000000000010000001......
```

What am I doing wrong?  I would have thought that the second call would return the first one moved to the right by 2 bits with 2 additional values, but this does not seem to be the case.

I am running Outlook 2013 on an Exchange Server.

Comment: It may be related to TimeZones. See: https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/94145-problem-with-freebusy-before-1pm-only/

Comment: @RyanWildry Thanks!  While timezones don't seem to have been the problem, while trying the solutions presented, I found that the time portion of the date is being ignored.  It starts at the beginning of the day regardless of the time portion that you put in there.

Comment: That would make sense then given what you were seeing. Should be an easy fix from there then. Re-reading the documentation just now, it's a Date value, but not including time.

Comment: @RyanWildry where's the documentation you're looking at?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.freebusy.aspx shows it as DateTime.

Comment: @RyanWildry Ahh, nevermind, I was looking at the wrong documentation.  I found the correct Outlook one that shows what you're saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `Start` parameter is a date parameter and not a DateTime parameter, so it will ignore the time, starting at the beginning of the day.

You just need to count the correct number of output bits to get the correct hour.

Instead of:

```
 debug.print myRoom.FreeBusy(#10/18/2016 11:00:00 AM#, 30, false)
```

Use:

```
 myVal = myRoom.FreeBusy(#10/18/2016#, 30, false)
 debug.print Mid(myVal, 22, len(myVal) - 22)
```